# Resolutions Issues with CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, width, resolution

I was making a website, with this HTML and CSS files :

https://pastebin.com/Ldh12gt7 for HTML

https://pastebin.com/8igc0DXm for CSS

It renders perfectly on my browser, and also renders perfectly on other browsers, but on my PC.

My resolution is 1920x1080, and the website is shown there https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtjVs.png

But, when a my friend tries to load it on a 1680x1050 resolution, the website appears to be like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M9aX.png

How can I fix this? I already tried to this in many ways.

First, I setted all width and height with percentages.

Then, I used normalized.css(no effect, so I removed it).

So, I tried to set font-size with various values(vw, vh, ch, em etc. etc.) but didn't work.

Finally, I tried to catch user's resolution with `@media` and set zoom value: it worked but I can't do it for every resolution that exists.

Oh, also, my friend tried to set his resolution to 1920x1080, but nothing changed.

Comment: You don't need to apply media query to all of resolution . Just try to implement it on breakpoints. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ .

Comment: Yeah, but as I said to Rajat Jain, even using this with "breakpoints", I should rewrite my entire code for every breakpoint, because every element has his own font-size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use media queries as:

Change the `*value*` accordingly.

To configure the CSS for the smaller screens then yours:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: *value*) {
    .class_name{
        //new CSS property
    }
}
```

To configure the CSS for the larger screens then yours:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: *value*) {
    .class_name{
        //new CSS property
    }
}
```

After that, you can check the responsiveness and view of your webpage on the different screen size devices using [this](http://sizzy.co) application

Comment: Thank you for the website you linked(Sizzy). This helps me a lot. But, I'm sorry, as I said, I already used media queries and it seems too boring for me to rewrite my entire code for every device. I mean, every element has his own font-size, and I can't rewrite font-size of every element for all resolutions on Sizzy.

Comment: Brother, its programming, it has nothing by itself. You have to do it, if one felt it boring then only way to get rid of it is not doing it. We can just give you the solution and this is the only way to do it. If you don't want it better design a non responsive design.